# Adding $2\pi$ not getting same value out of trig function

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am having a moment of weakness and lost the plot, why is this wrong

[image: Image of sine plots]

I assumed adding $2\pi$ would give the same result, clearly not the case on the graph (using desmos graphing tool)
$\sin (x + 2\pi)$ does not equal $\sin (x)$ in this plot

Comment: You plotted a sine and two vertical lines... What is the question about?

Comment: Are you working in degrees or radians?  Units are important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that desmos is plotting two different lines, the black vertical line

$$x = \frac16 \pi$$

and the red vertical line

$$x = \frac16 \pi + 2\pi$$

The purple graph is a graph of

$$\sin(\frac16 x)$$

which will look exactly the same if you write

$$\sin(\frac16x + 2\pi)$$

and is completely uncorrelated with the other two plots you made. In other words, when you wrote $x = \frac16 \pi$ and $x = \frac16\pi + 2\pi$ you didn't interact with the command $\sin \frac16 x$ you already had.

For it to work as expected you need to add the $2\pi$ inside the *first* command you have on desmos, or write a completely new one with $\sin(\frac16 x + 2\pi)$.

Comment: Good point (+1)

Comment: @Natalie Johnson I added a final line on how to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have $\sin x$, but $\sin(x/6),$ so when you add $2\pi$ to $x,$ this is what happens:

$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{6}(x+2\pi)\right) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{1}{6}2\pi\right) =\sin\left(\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right).$$

So you've really added only $\pi/3$ to the argument of $\sin.$

Comment: That is not quite what happened with the OP

Comment: But hang on a minute. The unit circle is 2 *pi   so a time period is always 2*pi... but sin(1/2 x) , sin(x) and sin (2x) all have different periods and not 2*pi

Comment: @NatalieJohnson No.  You seem to realize that these functions have different periods, but yet assert the "time period is always $2\pi$.  You might be confused because you're putting $\frac{1}{6}\pi$ and $\frac{1}{6}\pi + 2\pi$ in for $x$, where it gets multiplied by $\frac{1}{6}$ _again_.

Answer (score 0):

When you add $2\pi$ to $x$, $\frac16x$ increases only by $\frac13\pi$, which you shouldn't expect to preserve the sine.

The period of $\sin(\frac16x)$ is $6$ times $2\pi$, or $12\pi$.

Comment: this is true but doesn't address the issue of the OP

Comment: @RGS: You must have a different impression about what the OP's issue is than I (and two other answerers) have.

Comment: From my pov, the OP thinks he did something that he did not do. Notice he *did not* add $2\pi$ to any argument of any trig function.

Comment: @RGS whats the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding $2\pi$ to the argument, but to $x$:
$$\sin\left(\frac{x+2\pi}{6}\right) \neq \sin\left(\frac{x}{6}+2\pi\right)$$

Comment: That was not quite what happened